# Finding the distance between the centroids of the two plus marks in an image

Tags: image-processing

I want to find the centroid of the plus mark which is occluded by another object in the foreground???

i have tried active contour but it's not working.[two mis aligned plus marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxWwn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work. But maybe you could find the center of the crosses x and y co ords and then find the distance between those centers on each cross(feel like this could be done by using pixel locations). You could also use the color of the pixels to find out when a cross starts and ends. Good luck